# IIS 7.5 add ftp site on subdomain

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

I am running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit. I want to setup an ftp site for a specific domain. (ftp.mydomain.com)

Basic authentication is enabled.

I tried adding a specific Authorization Rule with Read/Write access    for the group of ftpusers, and for the user directly.

When I don't specify a host name in the binding, I am able to connect to the ftp site without problems.
When I specify ftp.mydomain.com, I get an error:

```
530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
```

When connecting from the local machine I get a more detailed error :

```
530-User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
Win32 error:   The system cannot find the file specified. 
Error details: File system returned an error.
530 End
```

I checked using nslookup on ftp.mydomain.com, and it responds with the correct ip address.
However I tested adding a website as a subdomain, I get the response "Non-existent domain".
So, I'm thinking there might be a problem with the dns settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS 7.5 FTP sites that are configured to be accessed from a specific hostname require the hostname as part of the username.

so an ftp site that responds only to ftp.mysite.com with a username of "user" will have a username that looks like this:

ftp.mysite.com|user
or 
ftp.mysite.com|domain\user